# .htaccess change file extention and force to https at the same time

Tags: .htaccess, https, file-extension

I want to change my url from .php to .html with .htaccess
also, I need this page force becoming to https
the above requirement are for the certain page not whole page...

```
eg. http://domain/filename/XXX.php => https://domain/filename/XXX.html
```

do anyone know how to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine some rules for https and extension modification

```
# Prevent endless loop
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# and redirect php to html
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html [L]

# Enforce https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Finally serve content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html /$1.php [L]
```