# URL Extensions removal

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

So recently, I have been trying to remove URL extensions from my website URL's, it has been successful and is working. However, when a URL extension has been removed from a page and ends in: **"/Contact"**. 
A user can change the URL to **"/Contact.php"** and the URL will stay like it. **I do not want that, regardless of them typing in "/Contact.php" I want it to revert to "/Contact".**

**Htaccess code:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: I answered a similar question only yesterday, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37634135/1741542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Apologies mate, it did work, sorry for my stupidness.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.