# Rogue URLs File Extension Removal

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have found some roque URLs within Google Search Console which I am trying to remove. Somehow Google has found a number of URLs with a .php file extension.

Within Stackoverflow I found this similar question : [URL Extensions removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647129/url-extensions-removal)
I added the following lines of code to my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I was hoping that if a browser requests a url with the file extension intact, it would re-direct to one without.

I don't think it is the above code that is failing, more likely a setting on my server - what other reasons would make this code not do as intended ?

https://www.martincorby.co.uk/test.php

https://www.martincorby.co.uk/test

Comment: This sounds like you have a much more serious problem. If your system was breached, you need to figure out how they got in, fix that, reinstall everything from known good sources, and restore your site data from backups.

Comment: How did you make sure that the file you saved those lines into is considered by the http server at all?

Comment: And on the other hand, how did you test how the http server behaves after installing those lines?

Comment: tripleee - Thanks for your comment. I am running my server with Plesk. Do you  suggest I delete the subscription. Create new and use a back up to re-instate ? For info, I was using this domain as a test bed for another domain on the server suffering in the same way.

Comment: arkascha - Thanks for your comment. With my limited knowledge of server management, I deleted the existing htaccess file, recreated new. Deleted the site cache in the browser and forced a fresh download (Shift F5)